# Erro: Sorry the aplication.... has stopped unexpectedly please try again Java Eclipse

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema com meu projeto e não sei como resolver.
Estou tentando criar uma calculadora usando alguns tutoriais da internet mas, está dando esse erro quando tento executar no emulador:
**Sorry The Aplication calculadora (proces com.example.app) has stopped unexpectedly. Please Try Again.**

**Meu Layout/ fragment_main.xml:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BTSomar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Valor1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
    android:text="Somar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Resultado"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BTSomar"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BTSomar"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Valor2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/BTSomar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BTSomar"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Valor1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Valor2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Valor2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Valor2"
    android:text="Digite o Segundo N°" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Valor1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Valor1"
    android:text="Digite o Primeiro N°" />
```

**Meu bin/res    AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Minha MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {



    EditText ET1, ET2, ETResultado;
    double num1, num2, resultado;
    Button BTsoma;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ET1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Valor1);
        ET2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Valor2);
        ETResultado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Resultado);
        BTsoma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTSomar);

        BTsoma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                num1 = Double.parseDouble(ET1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(ET2.getText().toString());
                resultado = num1 + num2;
                ETResultado.setText(String.valueOf(resultado));
            }
        });





        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**Meu LogCat**

```
04-13 01:45:14.200: E/FragmentManager(768): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.200: E/FragmentManager(768): Activity state:
04-13 01:45:14.200: D/FragmentManager(768):   Local FragmentActivity 40d230c8 State:
04-13 01:45:14.220: D/FragmentManager(768):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
04-13 01:45:14.220: D/FragmentManager(768):     mLoadersStarted=false
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):   Active Fragments in 40d23330:
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
04-13 01:45:14.250: D/FragmentManager(768):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
04-13 01:45:14.250: D/FragmentManager(768):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
04-13 01:45:14.260: D/FragmentManager(768):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
04-13 01:45:14.260: D/FragmentManager(768):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40d23330 in Segundo{40d230c8}}
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):       mActivity=com.example.babr.Segundo@40d230c8
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):   Added Fragments:
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.290: D/FragmentManager(768):   FragmentManager misc state:
04-13 01:45:14.290: D/FragmentManager(768):     mActivity=com.example.babr.Segundo@40d230c8
04-13 01:45:14.300: D/FragmentManager(768):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@40d233a8
04-13 01:45:14.310: D/FragmentManager(768):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
04-13 01:45:14.310: D/FragmentManager(768):   View Hierarchy:
04-13 01:45:14.330: D/FragmentManager(768):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d248e8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.350: D/FragmentManager(768):       android.widget.LinearLayout{40d24fb0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.350: D/FragmentManager(768):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d25b90 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020359 android:id/action_bar_container}
04-13 01:45:14.360: D/FragmentManager(768):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{40d26178 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035a android:id/action_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.370: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d272b0 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.370: D/FragmentManager(768):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{40d289b0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.390: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d28e10 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
04-13 01:45:14.390: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d29190 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
04-13 01:45:14.400: D/FragmentManager(768):               android.widget.LinearLayout{40d2aab0 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.400: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d2ae98 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
04-13 01:45:14.410: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{40d2b220 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.420: D/FragmentManager(768):                   android.widget.TextView{40d2b610 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102024d android:id/action_bar_title}
04-13 01:45:14.440: D/FragmentManager(768):                   android.widget.TextView{40d2c340 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102024e android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
04-13 01:45:14.440: D/FragmentManager(768):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{40d2c998 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035b android:id/action_context_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.460: D/FragmentManager(768):         android.widget.FrameLayout{40d2cf10 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
04-13 01:45:14.460: D/FragmentManager(768):           android.widget.RelativeLayout{40d2dfb8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2e550 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050040 app:id/textView1}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2eb70 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050041 app:id/textView2}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2f198 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050042 app:id/textView3}
04-13 01:45:14.490: D/FragmentManager(768):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d2d390 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035c android:id/split_action_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.500: D/AndroidRuntime(768): Shutting down VM
04-13 01:45:14.520: W/dalvikvm(768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-13 01:45:14.540: D/dalvikvm(768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 205K, 12% free 2572K/2916K, paused 8ms+34ms, total 213ms
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.babr/com.example.babr.Segundo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 11 more
04-13 01:45:17.000: I/Process(768): Sending signal. PID: 768 SIG: 9
```

**Alguem pode me ajudar?**

Comment: Pelo seu LogCat o erro se deve a um ponteiro nulo (`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`) e ocorreu na no método `onCreate` (linha 38 de `MainActivity.java`). Parece que a variável `BTsoma` está nula (mas olhando o seu arquivo de layout eu não consegui identificar o porque de não encontrar o botão pelo ID).

Comment: O erro pode estar também no emulador ou no próprio java eclipse? porque ja mexi no código várias vezes e nao resolveu :/

Comment: Acho pouco provável que seja o emulador, e menos ainda o Eclipse. Vc já consultou [essa thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011152/how-to-get-reference-to-a-button-created-in-a-custom-dialog-using-a-xml-layout) no SO em inglês? Parece ser um problema similar.

Comment: Tem algum objeto que está nulo no seu onCreate, aí está ocorrendo NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o erro é nessa linha de MainActivity.java:

```
BTsoma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

O motivo é porque `BTsoma` está recebendo o valor `null` nessa outra linha:

```
BTsoma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTSomar);
```

E o motivo disso é porque o layout que você passa para `setContentView()` NÃO CONTÉM um `Button` com id `@+id/BTSomar`.

De fato, você mostra o código de seu arquivo `fragment_main.xml` mas não é esse arquivo que você usa ao chamar `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Ao invés disso, usa um outro arquivo chamado `activity_main.xml`, que não é mostrado na sua pergunta e que provavelmente NÃO POSSUI o `Button` em questão.

**Obs.:** O fato de você ter um layout de `fragment` sugere que você tem um `fragment` dentro da sua `activity`. Uma alternativa é remover os elementos `Button`, `TextView` etc. desse `fragment_main.xml` e colocar em `activity_main.xml` para facilitar a sua vida, pois daí não ocorrerá mais a `NullPointerException`. Se porém você quiser manter o `fragment`, deverá chamar `BTsoma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { ...` dentro de um método do ciclo de vida do `fragment` e não da `activity` como está fazendo atualmente. Não sei exatamente qual método é esse porque não estou habituado a mexer com fragments, talvez seja `onAttach()` ou então `onActivityCreated()` mas mesmo sem saber o método exato essa recomendação já serve para ilustrar o problema, lembrando que o ciclo de vida do fragment não é totalmente vinculado ao da activity e portanto há momentos em que um não tem nenhuma relação com o outro. Você vai precisar entender o ciclo de vida de fragments para chamar esse `setOnClickListener` no momento certo.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que estas a chamar o layout ***(setContentView(R.layout.activity_main))*** em vez de chamar o layout ***(setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main))***, onde contém os botões e todos os objetos e deverias extender para uma Activity em vez de extender para ActionBarActivity

Muda de :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Para :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Answer (score -4):

Antes de atribuir o botão do layout XML, crie uma instância:

```
BTsoma = new Button(this);
BTsoma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTSomar);
```

Comment: A primeira linha do seu código é completamente desnecessária, pois na segunda linha o objeto criado na primeira linha será sobrescrito, independente se o valor que sobrescreverá será nulo ou uma referência válida para um botão.

Comment: Na verdade eu escrevi um detalhe errado, não é que o **objeto** será sobrescrito, a **referência para o objeto** será sobrescrita, sendo assim o primeiro objeto será deixado de lado.

Comment: Já passei por problema como esse há um tempo no desenvolvimento Android e precisei instanciar para não retornar null na referência a este. Isso somente no casos de objetos vindos de um layout XML.